# Generalising supercommutativity as a grading by the $1$-truncated sphere spectrum

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homotopy-theory, operads

A discussion that has been going recently is that [supersymmetry corresponds to grading over the sphere spectrum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236266), coming from an insight due to [Kapranov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07042).

To formalise such a statement, one needs a generalised notion of grading allowing the sphere spectrum as a possible candidate. [Section 2 of Bunke–Nikolaus's *Twisted differential cohomology*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3231) provides such a definition: given a monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$, we define a **$\mathcal{C}$-graded(-commutative) $\mathbb{E}_k$-ring** to be a lax (symmetric) $\mathbb{E}_k$-monoidal functor $(\mathcal{C},\otimes_{\mathcal{C}},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}})\to(\mathsf{Sp},\otimes_{\mathbb{S}},\mathbb{S})$.

For $\mathcal{C}$ an ordinary category, we replace $(\mathsf{Sp},\otimes_{\mathbb{S}},\mathbb{S})$ by $(\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}(\mathsf{Ab}),\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}},\mathbb{Z})$. Now, we have a bijection between the following data:

- Lax (symmetric) $\mathbb{E}_k$-monoidal functors $(\mathcal{C},\otimes_{\mathcal{C}},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}})\to((\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}(\mathsf{Ab}),\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}},\mathbb{Z})$;
- Lax (symmetric) $\mathbb{E}_k$-monoidal functors $(\mathsf{Ho}(\mathcal{C}),\otimes_{\mathcal{C}},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}})\to(\mathsf{Ab},\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}},\mathbb{Z})$.

so in this case an $\mathbb{S}$-graded(-commutative) ordinary ring corresponds simply to a $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded ring. From the description of $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$ as a symmetric monoidal category given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403218), one sees that such an object corresponds to the following definition:

> A **$\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded ring** is a pair $(R_\bullet,\{\sigma_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}})$ with
>
> - $R_\bullet$ a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring (corresponding to $\pi_0(\mathbb{S})\cong\mathbb{Z}$);
> - $\{\sigma_k\colon R_k\to R_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ a family of order $2$ automorphisms (corresponding to $\pi_1(\mathbb{S})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$);
>
> such that, for each $k,\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$, each $a\in R_k$, and each $b\in R_\ell$, we have
> $$\sigma_{k+\ell}(ab)=\sigma_{k}(a)\sigma_{\ell}(b).$$
> Moreover, $R$ is **$\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded commutative** if we additionally have
> $$
> ab
> =
> \begin{cases}
> ba                  &\text{if $\deg(a)\deg(b)$ is even,}\\
> \sigma_{\deg(a)+\deg(b)}(ab)    &\text{if $\deg(a)\deg(b)$ is odd}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> for each $a,b\in R_\bullet$.

Similarly, a $\tau_{\leq0}\mathbb{S}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{\mathsf{disc}}$-graded (commutative) ring (corresponding to "$0$-supercommutativity") is just an ordinary (commutative) ring with a $\mathbb{Z}$-gradation. The same discussion goes through replacing $\mathsf{Ab}$ by $\mathsf{Mod}_R$, defining a notion of **$\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded** (**commutative**) **$R$-algebras**.

**Main Question.** How far are $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded commutative rings from ($\mathbb{Z}$-graded) superalgebras, realising Kapranov's insight?

For instance, they contain each of the following classes of rings, all as full subcategories:

- The category of ordinary commutative rings as those $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded rings having everything in degree $0$ and such that $\sigma_k=\mathrm{id}_{R_k}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$;
- The category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded supercommutative rings (i.e. satisfying $ab=(-1)^{\deg(a)\deg(b)}ba$) as those $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded rings with $\sigma_k(a)=-a$ for each $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and each $a\in R_k$.

**Other questions:**

1. Has this specific notion appeared before in the literature?
2. What are interesting examples of $\tau_{\leq 1}\mathbb{S}$-graded commutative algebras that genuinely do not come from ordinary algebras or $\mathbb{Z}$-graded-commutative algebras?

Comment: Related: [In search of lost graded rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403448).

Comment: I don't understand your comment about how to embed $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ graded supercommutative rings as a full subcategory.  What happens when you multiply two elements in grading 1?

Comment: @VivekShende Oh right, that certainly doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: $\newcommand{\a}{\tau_{\leq1}\Sigma^{\infty-1}\mathbb{RP}^\infty}$(Somewhat tangentially related, but I think that if one replaces $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$ by $\a$, then  $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded supercommutative rings will embed fully faithfully into the category of "$\a$-graded rings", by a similar reason that $\mathbb{Z}$-graded supercommutative ones embed into that of $\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded ones; i.e. because $\pi_0(\a)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\pi_1(\a)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$.)

Comment: Is $\tau_{\le1}\Sigma^{\infty-1}\mathbb R{\mathrm P}^\infty$ a unit of some monoidal structure?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე (This is a guess, but) I think the homotopy category of $\Sigma^{\infty-1}\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ viewed as a monoidal $\infty$-groupoid might be described as in [Tim's answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403221) but with objects labelled by $\mathbb{Z}/2$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}$, carrying a similar monoidal structure.

Comment: If this is indeed the case, then a lax monoidal functor out of it to $\mathsf{Ab}$ would have a similar description to that of "$\tau_{\leq1}\mathbb{S}$-graded rings" given above, now recovering $\mathbb{Z}/2$-graded supercommutative rings as the special case where $\sigma_k(a)=-a$ for $k=0,1$.

Comment: (The reason for picking specifically $\Sigma^{\infty-1}\mathbb{RP}^\infty$ is that it satisfies a universal property making it into a kind of spectral analogue of $\mathbb{Z}/2$: a symmetric strong monoidal functor from it into a monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ is the same as an "involutory object" $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$, satisfying $A\otimes A\simeq\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}}$ up to coherent homotopy)